# Можно ли сделать java apk с телефона?

Tags: java, android, apk

Я изучаю java, и тут появилась идея сделать приложение .apk на телефон. Но в распоряжении у меня есть только этот самый телефон..) Как я могу сделать java приложение, скомпилировать его в файл .apk, используя только android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7831294/4827341

Comment: Ответ попроще: идём в маркет и ищем там мобильную IDE

Comment: https://members.loria.fr/CCerisara/androidCompile/

Comment: Нет, именно апк, чтобы кидать на другие телефоны(друзей например)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Termux, там есть все что надо

Comment: Вы можете улучшить ответ, немного расширив его. Например, добавив ссылки и примеры